# How can show few pictures in html/php from mysql (a gallery)

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, gallery

I want to make a gallery from some pictures that saved in mysql (in a specific border)
I tried this code but it only shows one picture(it work if we have one row in database(one picture)) :

```
<div class="main-panel">        
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row icons-list">
              <?php
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                  }
                
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                $theResult = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                
                ?>
                <?php foreach ($theResult as $picture): ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="<?=$picture["image"]?>" width="990" height="360">
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know if it's ok to use foreach here or not but i don't know what can i do too, **Thank you for your help**

Comment: Yes  it's ok to use foreach here. this code should display all pictures. Nothing to answer here

Comment: Database is ok. But it doesn't show all pictures and I don't know why. Anyway thank you

Comment: Who asked you about "database"? You should at least provide HTML generated by this code

Comment: I didn't understand. This code doesn't work well and i said everything I don't know what should I provide now?

Comment: **HTML generated by this code**

Comment: Edit your question and add the HTML that is being generated as suggested above. My guess is that either your query is coming out empty or you're missing something in the relative path of the images in the <img> tag.